# Compiling electron application using electron packager: bug on MACos with uws when opening the executable

Tags: macos, electron, darwin, electron-packager

When I compile my electron application with this command:

```
electron-packager ./dist my-application --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64  --icon=icon.icns
```

And then, I try to open the executable created, I have the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _SSL_library_init
  Referenced from: /Users/Documents/my-application/my-application-darwin-x64/my-application.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/uws/uws_darwin_57.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Any idea where it could come from? Which module? And how can I fix it?

The executable is actually working on Linux (`electron-packager ./dist my-application --overwrite --platform=linux  --arch=x64  --icon=icon.icns`) so I guess this error must be linked to an unsupported module on MACos.